# Any way to run multiple Google App Engine local instances for appengineFunctionalTest?

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle

**Background**

From the docs, at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

I see that by putting my functionalTests in /src/functionalTests/java does the following:

1. Starts the Local GAE instance
2. runs tests in the functionalTests directory
3. Stops the Local instance after the tests are complete

**My Issue**

For my microservices, I need to have 2 local servers for running my tests. 1 server is responsible for a lot of auth operations, and the other microservices talk to this server for some verification operations.

I've tried

```
appengineFunctionalTest.dependsOn ':authservice:appengineRun'
```

this does start the dependent server, but then it hangs and the tests don't continue. I see that I can set deamon = true and start the server on a background thread, but I can only seem to do that in isolation.

Is there a way to have a 'dependsOn' also be able to pass parameters to the dependent task? I haven't found a way to make that happen.

Or perhaps there is another way to accomplish this.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Are your micro-services separate GAE apps? Or separate GAE services inside the same app?

Comment: @DanCornilescu, they are separate GAE apps and are deployed separately. We want to be able to scale them up and track them independently.

Comment: I have not worked with Google App engine but I was able to start two selenium servers simultaneously by specifying different ports for the instances.  From the documentation, To change which port the local server uses, use the --port option:
dev_appserver.py --port=9999 [PATH_TO_YOUR_APP]... 


Can you try setting different ports for your instances?

Comment: Hey @Sid, the 2 servers are already configured to use different ports.